# Where can I find "My preapproved payments" on a personal verified account in the sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've followed this steps https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/ and I finally got a billing ID to make reference transactions. However, before doing that, I would like to see where is this approved agreement in the sandbox.
I've logged whith the personal verified test account in the sandbox, but I can not find the "My preapproved payments" section, which is the place where I suppose this kind of information should be. Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start at the **My Account** tab.  Navigate through **Profile** to **My Money**.  Click **Update** in the **My preapproved payments section**.  You may need to continue by clicking on **preapproved payment plans** since they aren't all listed in one place.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-manage-preapprovals might be a shortcut. The page it leads to has a **Back to My Profile** link.  *That* page has a **My preapproved payments** link (with a dotted underline?!) that will take you to the other preapproved payments page.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer.I've tried that but when I clicked in "My money" it keeps loading and no info is shown.

Comment: @Anne - Please try the updated link in my answer.  Somehow the PayPal Sandbox always puts up a fight re: preapproved payments.

Comment: Finally!!!! I don't know what was happening but right now, and with your link, I can see the billing agreements. Thank you very muck!!

Comment: @Anne - You're welcome very muck _[sic]_.  Glad to ease the pain of someone else chasing preapproved payments.

Comment: @HABO By seeing your experience,would you mind to look at my question please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625518/paypal-adaptive-preapproval-payment